# OLEDB FOXPRO LOCK RECORD

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb, foxpro

how to lock a foxpro table that has sono='12345' by OLEDB instead of locking whole table? using rlock(), i can lock records by number but no idea how to lock records by using filter.

here is how i lock table by record number

`string vfp = "[ SET EXCLUSIVE OFF ] + chr(13) + ";
            vfp += " [ USE table IN 0 ALIAS a_table ] +  chr(13) +";
            vfp += " [ LOCK('1,2,3,4', 'a_table ') ]";`

```
        dbConn.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand())
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "Exec( " + vfp + " ) ";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: What is your purpose of locking the records via OleDB. The lock will only be available for the duration of the connection, and if you disconnect before finishing whatever your were trying to do, you will lose the locks anyhow.  Jerry's option appears to be closest for a solution of multiple record locking.  However, it looks like you'll be doing more, and eventually try to build an entire procedure run via ExecScript() call.  I don't necessarily see this as practicle.

Answer (score 0):

If you position the 'record pointer' on the record you wish to lock, and then call RLOCK() with no parameters, the record will be locked.

This sequence of commands will do it:

```
  SET EXCLUSIVE OFF
  USE table IN 0 ALIAS a_table
  SELECT a_table
  LOCATE FOR sono='12345'
  RLOCK()
```

This assumes that the LOCATE command actually finds a record with sono='12345'.

Or, you can use the SEEK command or SEEK() function if you have an index you can use.

Comment: how do i locate all record that has sono='12345'?

Comment: As Jerry said, you'd need to build a list of the record numbers of records with sono='12345', then lock the records.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to SET FILTER TO , then loop through the filter and store the record numbers to a var, then RLOCK based on the record numbers in the var.

```
 //Perhaps use a SQL Command to filter
 USE mytable in o ALIAS a_table
 SELECT RECNO() AS ID FROM mytable INTO CURSOR myCursor NOFILTER
 SELECT myCursor
 idList = ""
 LOCATE   &&Same as GO TOP
 SCAN
    idList = idList + ALLTRIM(STR(ID)) + ", "
 ENDSCAN
 SET MULTILOCKS ON   &&Remember to turn this ON
 isAllRecordsLocked = RLOCK(idList, 'a_table')  &&Perform RLOCK()
```